# How to conditionally define azure template parameter?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template

In an azure template parameters are allowed however you cannot define variables ... I need to conditionally define a parameter in an azure pipeline template based on a different parameter

Here is my desired syntax which throws an error

```
---
parameters:
  - name: my_host_url
    type: string
    ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'prod') }}:
      default: 'https://example.com'
    ${{ else }}:
      default: 'https://dev.example.com'
```

above throws error

```
A template expression is not allowed in this context
```

something similar to above is possible for variables  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-192-update#new-yaml-conditional-expressions   however since I am in an azure pipeline template, variables are not allowed so I am defining parameters not variables

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible on parameters declaration. When you call template and provide parameters, that's fine. But here it is impossible.